# Как организовать поиск по сайту с дополнительными критериями

Tags: php, mysql

Как организовать поиск по сайту с дополнительными критериями вот на подобии этого http://auto.drom.ru/
просто покажите как это примерно сделать заранее благодарен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть таблица (offer):

```
id | mark | model    | year | price |
1  | BMW  | 3-Series | 2008 | ..... |
```

Следовательно можно сделать запрос:

```
select * from offer where mark='BMW'
```

Для того что-бы сделать запрос, нужна форма:

```
<form action="script.php">
   Марка:
   <select name="mark">
       <option value="">-любая-</option>
       <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
   </select>
   Модель:
   <select name="model">
       <option value="">-любая-</option>
       <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
   </select>
   Год выпуска от: <input type="text" name="year_from" />
   до: <input type="text" name="year_to" />
   <input type="submit" value="Искать" />
</form>
```

Собственно есть script.php

```
$sql = "select * from offer";
$where = array();
if (!empty($GET["mark"])) {
    $where[] = "mark='" . $GET["mark"] . "'"; 
}
if (!empty($GET["model"])) {
    $where[] = "model='" . $GET["model"] . "'";
}
// и так далее
if (count($where)) {
    $sql .= ' where ' . implode(' and ', $where);
}
// дальше выполняешь запрос и выводишь результаты
```

Answer (score 1):

Берешь делаешь форму в HTML, потом после нажатия кнопки эти все выбранные параметры шлешь на сервер, а там их обрабатываешь ну и создаешь запрос по нужным полям с нужными условиями.

В чем проблема?

Comment: проблема в том что он должен собрать общую информацию и вывести результаты

Comment: Не общую информацию, а информацию по запросу от пользователя, не так все сложно ведь.